# Graph API: Get email recipient adress

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I parse through my email with the following command :

```
$EmailQuery = "$GraphURI/users/myemail@example.com/mailboxFolders/MyFolder/messages"
$EmailResponseFirst = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $EmailQuery -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $AccessToken"} -ContentType "application/json"
$EmailResponse = $EmailResponseFirst.value | Out-String

foreach ($Email in $EmailResponse) {
$RecipientAddress = $Email.toRecipients.emailAddress[0].emailAddress
Write-Host $RecipientAddress
```

It outputs nothing but if I append to my script this :

```
Write-Host "($Email.from | ConvertFrom-Json).odata.etag"
```

I get this output :

```
@odata.etag                : W/"CQAAABYA"
id                         : AAMkADQ5M
createdDateTime            : 2023-03-06T10:22:22Z
lastModifiedDateTime       : 2023-03-06T10:22:24Z
changeKey                  : CQA
categories                 : {}
receivedDateTime           : 2023-03-06T10:22:22Z
sentDateTime               : 2023-03-06T10:22:18Z
hasAttachments             : False
internetMessageId          : <1BC4@sender.com>
subject                    : Test
bodyPreview                : Test
importance                 : normal
parentFolderId             : AAMkADQ
conversationId             : AAQ
conversationIndex          : AQHZ
isDeliveryReceiptRequested : 
isReadReceiptRequested     : False
isRead                     : True
isDraft                    : False
webLink                    : https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMk3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem
inferenceClassification    : focused
body                       : @{contentType=html; content=<html><head>
                         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>Test</body></html>}
sender                     : @{emailAddress=}
from                       : @{emailAddress=}
toRecipients               : {@{emailAddress=}}
ccRecipients               : {}
bccRecipients              : {}
replyTo                    : {}
flag                       : @{flagStatus=notFlagged
```

How could I get the values of the "toRecipients" field from that output?

Comment: What exactly do you do with `$EmailResponse` to get that ouput? `$EmailResponse.toRecipients`? `$EmailResponse |ConvertTo-Csv`?

Comment: Hi, I've added more context to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$response.value` is an array of all messages. Iterate through all messages and foreach message iterate through all `toRecipients` and write their mail

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $EmailQuery -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $AccessToken"} -ContentType "application/json"
$messages = $response.value

foreach ($message in $messages) {
    foreach ($recipient in $message.toRecipients){
        Write-Host $recipient.emailAddress.address
    }
}
```